# How to dynamically export a graph to the excel sheet along with the corresponding data in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to export a graph to an excel sheet with the corresponding data.Currently i have created an mvc application and in the download button click, am able to export the data stored in the array to the excel sheet.But my main task is to bring a dynamic graph along with the data to the excel and that graph should change dynamically when the value in the excel is modified.Please help me in this.Am just a beginner in this,so....
Here is my controller.cs code...

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]

    public void  download()
    {
        var data = new[]{ 
                           new{ Name="Ram", Email="ram@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-3333" },
                           new{ Name="Shyam", Email="shyam@techbrij.com", Phone="159-222-1596" },
                           new{ Name="Mohan", Email="mohan@techbrij.com", Phone="456-222-4569" },
                           new{ Name="Sohan", Email="sohan@techbrij.com", Phone="789-456-3333" },
                           new{ Name="Karan", Email="karan@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-1234" },
                           new{ Name="Brij", Email="brij@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-3333" }                       
                  };

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Contact.xls");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        WriteTsv(data, Response.Output);
        Response.End();
        Response.Write ("downloaded");
    }

    public void WriteTsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, TextWriter output)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
        {
            output.Write(prop.DisplayName); // header
            output.Write("\t");
        }
        output.WriteLine();
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                output.Write(prop.Converter.ConvertToString(
                     prop.GetValue(item)));
                output.Write("\t");
            }
            output.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}

In the index.cshtml..

```
   @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    @{using (Html.BeginForm("download","home"))
    {
         <div>
            <button>Download</button>
        </div>
    }}

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're currently exporting a text file with the wrong content-type and Excel is (kindly(?)) covering up your mistakes for you.   If you want a chart, you'll have to export an `.xlsx`, not text.    You can use OpenXml (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) or any wrapper (ClosedXml is one) as OpenXml is not the most obvious API.

Comment: Thanks for that information.As i told before am new in this field..So please help me to correct my code.What change i should do in my code to achieve this.You people are the genius guys.

Comment: A code answer is too broad for SO. You can google how to manipulate xlsx files in c#.

Comment: I been google to find the manipulation,but couldn't understand anything as am very poor in this..please help..

Answer (score 1):

Something we did before is use excel templates. Here are the steps:

1. Create an excel file with chart on it. It should reference a sheet with data on it. By default the data sheet would of course be blank
2. In C#, manipulate this excel file to insert your data in
3. Return the file to the user for download
4. Chart should not be dynamic and change according to user  changes to the data sheet as well since this is referenced.

This is the easiest step i can think of. I might not have given you the exact codes on how to do it but im sure you can search for it in the net. 
Hope i was able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the help.But the data what i have might change and accordingly the graph also need to change.If i create a excel sheet with chart on it, how will it get changed when the data is modified.

Comment: Excel graphs are *data-driven*.  You change the data, the graph changes.  Unless you stuff a pre-rendered bitmap on there of course!

Comment: Is it possible to export the graph to the excel without as an image.                  @freedomn-m

Comment: Not sure what that means - but if you follow @TheProvost 's steps, you should be good to go.

Comment: @TittoThomas I have no clue how you created your chart so i wouldnt know. But if you can create a bitmap image of it then you can export it an excel file as an image. You would have to use interop libraries or 3rd party controls for that though..not csv files.

The steps i gave you is the most dynamic way to do it. If you export an image it wont change if you change the data in it

Comment: I haven't created any chart till now. I don't know how to create chart.

Comment: With the above code what i should do to create the chart from the data provided.@freedomn-m

Comment: @TittoThomas Your question was how to export a graph. That assumes that you already have a chart in the page